# Simultaneous Equation Models and Endogeneity

Tags: endogeneity, simultaneous-equation

I wanted to ask a question about Simultaneous Equations Models. Supposed I had the following system of equations:

$
(1):y_1=\alpha+ \beta_1 y_{2}+ \beta_2x_{1}+\beta_3x_{2}+\varepsilon_i \\
(2):y_2=\nu+ \gamma_1 y_{1}+ \gamma_2z_{1}+\gamma_3x_{1}+\mu_i 
$

As you can see there is mutual causation  running between $ y_1$ and $y_2$. Here we could use something like 3SLS to estimate the above.

However, suppose that $ z_1$ in equation (2) is endogenous. Is it possible to estimate equation (2) alone using 2SLS, under the assumption that there is some valid instrument for $ z_1$, and then apply standard estimation techniques for the SEM as a whole?

Comment: Hi: You want to do 2SLS for (2) ( also called IV ) by using an instrument for $z_{1}$ but you can't because $y_1$ and $y_2$ are still in both equations. At a glance it looks like you need instruments for either ( $x_1$ and $y_1$ ) OR ($x_1$ and $y_2$) AND in either case, $z_{1}$. Then you can do 2SLS on the system as a whole.

Comment: How can $y_1$ cause $y_2,$ but $y_2$ also cause $y_1?$ Do you mean that the variables are evaluated at different times? Causes must precede effects, not be exactly simultaneous with them.

Comment: @AdrianKeister To give an example off the top of my head, suppose that $ y_1$ is corruption, $y_2$ is say GDP per capita,  and $z_1$ is say a country's strength of property rights protection.  There could be multiple distinct mechanisms linking these variables.

Comment: @DarkenExcalibur Maybe I wasn't clear in my question. The law of cause-and-effect is that causes must precede effects. Not be simultaneous with, and certainly not come after, but *precede*. It is therefore absolutely impossible for $y_1(t)$ to cause $y_2(t)$ and for $y_2(t)$ to cause $y_1(t).$ It is certainly possible to have feedback, but that would look like, e.g., $y_1(t-2)$ causing $y_2(t-1),$ which in turn causes $y_1(t).$